# Running show() twice gives same results for rand() function for Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

The below produces random numbers that differ per row as expected. So, fine. But I am apparently missing some basic aspect apparently in thinking.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.range(10).withColumn("randomNum",F.rand())
df.show(truncate=False)
```

returning:

```
+---+-------------------+
|id |randomNum          |
+---+-------------------+
|0  |0.8128581612050234 |
|1  |0.40656852491856355|
|2  |0.9444869347865689 |
|3  |0.10391423680687417|
|4  |0.05285485891027453|
|5  |0.5140906081158558 |
|6  |0.900727341820192  |
|7  |0.11046600268909801|
|8  |0.6509183512961298 |
|9  |0.5060097759646045 |
+---+-------------------+
```

Then invoking `show()` again - the special Action below, why do we get the same random number sequence again as per first time round? Is `show()` overriding the traditional Action approach on some aspects as it sees that it is the same DF? If so, that is not true for all methods in pyspark, etc. I am running this in 2 cells in a Databricks Notebook.

**Looking at the SPARK UI, it uses the same seed twice. Why? Deterministic aspect, seems to be at odds with the concept of Action as we are taught.**

```
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of random being initialized only once per partition. [Source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.2/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/randomExpressions.scala#L101).

Hence, if partition layout is not changed, that same initial seed is being used in every consecutive execution, and thus `rand` generates the same sequence.

When partitions are NOT fixed, `rand`'s behavior becomes non-deterministic, which is documented (in the source, at least) through [Spark JIRA-13380](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13380).

Comment: Well, that is sort of what I am saying, and you say think. show is an Action. But a special one. What you actually say is that you probably agree with my logic, or not? To make deterministic.

Comment: I looked at the source, but I am not good enuff to assess it, it does talk about non-determinsitic I note.

Comment: May be in a chat we can discuss code. Spark and scala is not same as pure scala. A new Action should it all again.

Comment: The question was "Why?" The answer is -- because a **pseudo**-random generator, when initialized with the same seed, produces the same result/sequence. Besides, there is nothing special about `show()` action.

Comment: Well, we are not understanding each other and no bad day. Action is action and it should start all again imo. So...let's not twist on the definition of why...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have the problem, but found a nice [blog article](https://blog.demofox.org/2013/07/06/the-incredible-time-traveling-random-number-generator/) . SO basically instead of creating a RN with a PRNG, he uses a hash function on the rownumbers of a sorted dataframe. This ensures that the generated random numbers are reproducible and deterministic. This approach depends a lot on the quality of the hash algorithm as he mentioned. Following a quick and dirty implementation from me, whihc uses spark 2.4.8, thats why I am not using xxhash instead the .hash() method by PySpark which uses the Murmurhash3 algorithm.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

def distributed_random_number(indf:pyspark.sql.DataFrame, col_name:str, unique_keys:list) -> pyspark.sql.DataFrame:
    """
    This function creates a new column with a deterministic random number integer. Other implementations in PySpark like rand() are not determnistic! 
    
    Arguments: 
    ----------
    indf:pyspark.sql.DataFrame
    col_name:str
        Column name of the new random number column. 
    unique_keys:list
        Unique keys inside the dataframe, which are needed for sorting in the beginning. 
    
    Returns: 
    ----------
    pyspark.sql.DataFrame
        Input dataframe including the new random number column. 
    """
    if isinstance(unique_keys, str): 
        unique_keys = [unique_keys]
    if not all(col in indf.columns for col in unique_keys) or col_name in indf.columns: 
        raise ValueError(f"Either the given 'col_name' is already in the indf columns or not all columns in 'unique_keys' are in the indf columns.")
    
    return indf.orderBy(unique_keys).\
            withColumn('monotonically_increasing_id_tmp', monotonically_increasing_id()).\
            withColumn(col_name, F.hash('monotonically_increasing_id_tmp')).drop('monotonically_increasing_id_tmp')

df_with_random_col = distributed_random_number(df_without_random_col, 'random_col', 'unique_id')
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Not sure i get yr point

Comment: A good Hash function kinda behaves like a random number generator, but always returns the for the same input the same output. So when you now sort the dataframe by some primary key, add a new column which enumerates all the rows in your dataframe and then use this rownumber as a input to your hash function, the generated output is like generated by a random number generator but deterministic.